# Live Mail folder and Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I created a New account (MS live Email account) on Thunderbird and set the incoming protocol to IMAP and "pop3.live.com" Port No 995 , SSL to SSL/TLS and Outgoing protocol to SMTP and "smtp.live.com" Port No 25, SSL to STARTTLS

However, there are sub-folders in my Web based Live Email account which are not appearing when I create the account in Thunderbird.

How can I get them to show up?

[image: edited screenshot]

Comment: Where have you seen that Microsoft supports IMAP... It would be a great news

Comment: I saw some random links that were showing IMAP thingy , but dont know how to configure it . I always get the error now even i beginning to feel its not possible , but gmail did it i a second. And by looking at your comment i feel u will also not be able to help me :-(

Comment: This unanswered question is 5+ years old and deals with a version of Ubuntu which is EOL. Microsoft Live and Thunderbird have changed since then and this question, as is, is likely `not reproducible`. VTC as such.